# 'changefreq' => 'weekly' is not showing in xml after generated xml in Custom URL Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sitemaps

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
class Sitemap extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap
{
   
    public function getCustomurlCollection()
    {
        $siteMapcollection = array();
        /* if want to add multiple url then load your custom collection and set  */

           /*foreach ($siteMapcollection as $custom) { */
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

                    $siteMapcollection[] = new DataObject([
                        'id'         => "test",
                        // 'url'        => $baseurl,
                        'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                    ]);
             /*     } */
            return $siteMapcollection;

    }
    public function _initSitemapItems()
    {
        parent::_initSitemapItems(); 

        array_unshift($this->_sitemapItems,$this->_sitemapItems[] = new DataObject([
            'changefreq' => 'daily',
            'priority' => '0.1',
            'collection' => $this->getCustomurlCollection(),
        ]));
        



       
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace '**changefreq**' => 'daily' with '**change_frequency**' => 'daily'